# Div in Div: layout question

Tags: html, css

I created the following layout:

```
<div class="title" id="m1">
    <div class="chkbx">something</div>
    <div class="name">
        <a href="#" onclick="doSomething('1');">Dummy #1</a>
    </div>
</div>
// .. the div above repeats several times
```

I'm using the folowing CSS:

```
div.title { border: 1px black solid; }
div.chkbx {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    padding:2px;
    text-align:right;
    width:5%;
}
 div.name {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

and would expect a border around all of `class=title`, but see only some strange lines at the top. Please let me know what I do wrong.

Many many thanks!

Comment: Please show us the rest of your CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably floating the content. Set `overflow: hidden` on the container.

- http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/ explains why you get this behaviour
- http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59 lists various ways to avoid it, most of which are better than those described above, and including the overflow approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding one more element in `.title` with `clear: both;` style.

Your `.title` elemnt contains only floated elements, and floated elements don't stretch their parent elements, so `.title` element is rendered as if it were empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here you wrong cause of you missed clear side of DIVs. If you use div with float:left/right, for start new line you must use clear:both with div.

-- JUST ADD ONE DIV WITH CLEAR:BOTH;

```
<div class="title" id="m1">
<div class="chkbx">something</div>
<div class="name">
    <a href="#" onclick="doSomething('1');">Dummy #1</a>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```